# Protractor 2.5.1 ReferenceError: testFn is not defined

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, jasmine2.0

I recently upgraded to protractor 2.5.1 and all of my tests are now failing. I suspect it is something to do with Jasmine but I'm not sure how to fix. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.
Here is the error I receive:

```
Should login successfully
Message:
ReferenceError: testFn is not defined
Stack:
ReferenceError: testFn is not defined
at Object. (c:\GlobalSeedField\Gsfm_Web\EndToEnd.Tests\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:81:16)
at attemptAsync (c:\GlobalSeedField\Gsfm_Web\EndToEnd.Tests\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1809:24)
at QueueRunner.run (c:\GlobalSeedField\Gsfm_Web\EndToEnd.Tests\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1764:9)
at QueueRunner.execute (c:\GlobalSeedField\Gsfm_Web\EndToEnd.Tests\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1753:10)
at queueRunnerFactory (c:\GlobalSeedField\Gsfm_Web\EndToEnd.Tests\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:614:35)
at Object.fn (c:\GlobalSeedField\Gsfm_Web\EndToEnd.Tests\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:2338:13)
at attemptAsync (c:\GlobalSeedField\Gsfm_Web\EndToEnd.Tests\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1809:24)
at QueueRunner.run (c:\GlobalSeedField\Gsfm_Web\EndToEnd.Tests\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1764:9)
at QueueRunner.execute (c:\GlobalSeedField\Gsfm_Web\EndToEnd.Tests\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1753:10)
at queueRunnerFactory (c:\GlobalSeedField\Gsfm_Web\EndToEnd.Tests\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:614:35)
```

Here is my test, however the browser never even navigates to the baseUrl, it just shuts down.

```
import {Login} from "./Login";

describe("Login", () => {

beforeAll(() => {
    browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
});

it("Should login successfully", () => {
    Log.login(browser.params.login.username, browser.params.login.password);
    expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toBe("/");
});
});
```

Comment: What if you would reinstall `protractor` from scratch?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the response.  I have tried to revert to 2.1.0, which is what I had before, but I still get the same error.

Comment: But what if you go forward to the currently latest protractor 3.0.0?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot go forward to 3.0.0 as our build servers have node versions <4. 2 

I ended up reverting to 2.1.0 with a fresh npm install. Once the build servers are updated I will try to skip to 3.0.0.  Thanks!!

Comment: What version of `npm` are you using? Unless you are using `npm@3` it seems odd that jasmine2wd is at `node_modules` and not `node_modules/protractor/node_modules`. I hate to say it but blowing away `node_modules` and reinstalling might help.

Comment: Also what is `Log` in the test? Can you reproduce this without using any helpers or external modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are running in the *"strict" mode* and `jasminewd2` had [this problem](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd/pull/67) when `testFn` was undefined. The fix was made in November and since `Protractor` depends on `jasminewd2`, upgrading to the latest Protractor would, surely, fix the issue.